# How to eliminate if/elseif/else chain for SObjectType variables?

Tags: sobjecttype, switch

In a few places I have code of this nature:

```
private static void myMethod(SObjectType t) {
    if (t == Claim__c.SObjectType) xyzForClaims();
    else if (t == Account.SObjectType) xyzForAccounts();
    else if (t == Contact.SObjectType) xyzForContacts();
    ...
}
```

for a great many `SObjectType`s. It's a bit ugly, and if called a lot all the `if`/`else if` tests could become expensive.

It would be great if this was supported:

```
private static void myMethod(SObjectType t) {
    switch on t {
        case Claim__c.SObjectType { xyzForClaims(); }
        case Account.SObjectType { xyzForAccounts(); }
        case Contact.SObjectType { xyzForContacts(); }
        ...
    }
}
```

but it isn't. The nearest thing I can think of (short of refactoring into multiple classes) is:

```
private static void myMethod(SObjectType t) {
    switch on String.valueOf(t) {
        case 'Claim__c' { xyzForClaims(); }
        case 'Account' { xyzForAccounts(); }
        case 'Contact' { xyzForContacts(); }
        ...
    }
}
```

Am I missing a better approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative solution (for now) would be:

```
static void myMethod(SObjectType t) {
  switch on t.newSobject() {
    when Claim__c claim { xyzForClaims(); }
    when Account account { xyzForAccounts(); }
    when Contact contact { xyzForContacts(); }
    ...
  }
}
```

It is possible that the sObjectType (and others) will be supported in the future, so make sure you check the release notes in the future. Also see [this related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/262841).

Comment: Yeah sneaky. But seems so wrong...

Comment: @KeithC I agree, it'd be nice to have sObjectType as a native supported type. It was said that the initial release of switch was to "get something out there" and that future releases may support more types (obviously, safe harbor, yada, yada). I'd use this method for now, as I feel it would be the easiest to convert to supporting sObjectType directly if that ever gets released.

Comment: Good point. Don't want to lose the compile time checking. And thanks for the performance info on the earlier question; I would have assumed more cost so good to know.

Comment: Just checked that the variable e.g. `claim` can't be left out but the same name e.g. `x` or `sob` can be used for each case which reads better when that variable isn't used.

Comment: @KeithC I never tried using the same name. That's a good thing to know.